# Python string split returns weird characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
string = '''In your opinion, will BCH/USD trade above 1500 USD (+9.65%) at anу timе bеfore Арril 28?
Indicаtоr: 60.76%'''

splited = string.split()
print(splited)

# Using Regex
import re 

res = re.findall(r"\w+ \d+\?", string)
print(res)
```

I want to grab the date April 28 from this string. If I split the string it produces output like this

```
an\xd1\x83', 'tim\xd0\xb5', 'b\xd0\xb5fore', '\xd0\x90\xd1\x80ril', '28?
```

If I use regex it only returns

```
ril 28
```

How do I grab the date or convert the string so that it acts like an ordinary string ?

**[Demo](https://repl.it/@adityathebe/TimelyRunnyNamebinding)**

Comment: Bit of an inverse world, given that the duplicate is actually a copy of the original (now closed/deleted) question. See the first comment in the duplicate. Weird world.

Answer (score 1):

The weird characters are NOT Latin characters.

For example, the Y in the word "anу" is actually Cyrillic lowercase У, and the word "Арril" contains Cyrillic А and Cyrillic lowercase Р.

Those characters, however, looks identical to Latin ones in quite some computer fonts, and you're just confused by those Cyrillic characters.

Comment: `$ charinfo 'anу'`
`U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A [Ll]`
`U+006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N [Ll]`
`U+0443 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER U [Ll]`